# 分散、標準偏差、相関係数

Tags: python, python3, matplotlib

これのどこを変えたら、分散、標準偏差、相関係数が出るようになりますか？

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statistics
import numpy
x = []
y = []
for i in range(1901,2021):
    x.append(i)
    y.append(numpy.sin(i))
a = statistics.variance(y)
b = print("...".format(...)), numpy.corrcoef
print("分散={}".format(a))
print("標準偏差={}".format(b))
cor = numpy.correcoef(x,y)
print("相関係数={}".format(cor[1][0]))
```

Comment: 書き間違いなのかもしれませんが、`statistics,variance` は `statistics.variance` です(`,`(カンマ) ではなく `.`(ドット))。同様に `statistics.stdev`, `print("...".format(...))`, `numpy.corrcoef` になります。

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError        と出てきます。どうしたらよいでしょうか？

Comment: 見落としていましたが、`import matplotlib,pyplot as plt` を `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` にします(こちらも `,` を `.` に)。

Comment: NameErrorとなってしまいます。質問のところに書き換えたのがあります。どこか違うところはありませんか？

Answer (score 0):

ModuleNotFoundErrorとなっているのはライブラリがないからだと思われます。
`pip install matplotlib`
`pip install numpy`
を行ってください。ライブラリがないかと思われます。

Comment: これはコードの中に追加したらいいのですか？無知ですみません。

Comment: どの環境で開発していますでしょうか？VSCodeなどで開発しているのでしたら、コードを実行するターミナルにいれていただければインストールができます。

Answer (score 0):

コメントで指摘した通り、`,`(カンマ)を `.`(ドット)に修正します。

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import statistics
import numpy

x = []
y = []
for i in range(1901,2021):
    x.append(i)
    y.append(numpy.sin(i))

a = statistics.variance(y)
b = statistics.stdev(y)
print("分散={}".format(a))
print("標準偏差={}".format(b))
cor = numpy.corrcoef(x,y)
print("相関係数={}".format(cor[1][0]))
```