# 相関係数を求めるには

Tags: python, python3, matplotlib

分散と標準偏差は出てくるのですが、相関係数が出てきません。
どのように変更したら良いでしょうか？

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statistics
import numpy
x = []
y = []
for i in range(1901,2021):
    x.append(i)
    y.append(numpy.sin(i))
a = statistics.variance(y)
b = b = statistics.stdev(y)
print("分散={}".format(a))
print("標準偏差={}".format(b))
cor = numpy.correcoef(x,y)
print("相関係数={}".format(cor[1][0]))
```

Comment: 前の質問に付いた[@metropolis さんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/75967/26370)の`b = statistics.stdev(y)`の行を変な風に書き変えているからでは？

Comment: 直してみたら標準偏差は出てきたのですが、相関係数が出てきません、どうしたらよいでしょうか？

Comment: jupyterではない素のpythonで@metropolisさんの回答をそのまま実行したら表示されましたけど。jupyterをいったん終了・再起動してから試してみるとか、jupyterではなく素のpythonで試してみるとかしてみてください。あとpythonは3.9.5でmatplotlibやnumpyは最新版にしていますので、そうした版数も考慮してみてください。

Comment: 「相関係数が出てきません。」とはどういう意味でしょうか？（エラーが発生するのか？間違った数値が出るのか？等）

Comment: なぜか `numpy.correcoef` と書き変えていますね。正しくは `numpy.corrcoef` です。